# TinyMCE always converts <iframe> to entities

Tags: php, iframe, mysqli, upload, tinymce

I need to upload iframe tag to my database for some testing reasons. But I can't setup TinyMCE not to convert the "<" and ">" elements to "& lt;" and & gt;".

I've read that entity_encoding: 'raw' leaves every char as I typed, only converts < > and some others... Great... :D

I tried:
- entities : '60,lt,62,gt'
- invalid_elements: 'iframe'

and other stuffs like these but I could't get it work.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: try adding it using <pre></pre> tags

Answer (score 0):

Enable TinyMCE code plugin and add your iframe tag in source code editing mode. add plugins: "code" to the initialization code as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "code"
});
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/